# Group of order $60$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**[NBHM_2006_PhD screening test_Algebra]**

> Let $G$ be a group of order $60$, pick out the true statements:
>
> a. $G$ is abelian
>
> b. $G$ has a subgroup of order $30$.
>
> c. $G$ has subgroups of order $2$, $3$, and $5$.
>
> d. $G$ has subgroups of order $6$, $10$, and $15$.

---

My Attempt:

a is false because $A_5$ is an non abelian group of order $60$.

For  b,c,d I have no idea.if $G$ was abelian then $c$ is correct by cauchy theorem .

Comment: Mind that Cauchy's Theorem (If $p$ divides the order of a group $G$, then there is an element in $G$ of order $p$) applies to any finite group. Statement b is false, again $A_5$ gives the counterexample (why?). Can you work out statement d for the group $A_5$?

Comment: Yes another badly worded question! For a,b, and d, the answer is that it depends on which group of order 60 $G$ is. They are all true for the cyclic group of order 60. (But I didn't downvote it!)

Comment: I've deleted some off-topic comments. Patience, please either politely ask for the reason for a downvote, or don't say anything. Also, as a reminder to everyone, downvoting without leaving a comment is acceptable here ([see e.g. the answers on this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3153/264)), and there's nothing anyone can do to make people only vote for "good" reasons so [don't worry about it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1722/264).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- There is a *non-abelian* simple group of order $60$. Thus, $(a)$ is false.
- We note that $(b)$ is false for precisely the same reason as $(a)$. There is a non-abelian *simple* group of order $60$.
- $(c)$ is true. This is because, by Cauchy's theorem, there is an element of those orders specified. The subgroup those elements generate will respectively be the required subgroup.
- This is a bit tricky if one does not want to use the fact that the non-abelian simple group of order $60$ is the alternating group on $5$ symbols, $A_5$. It is a straight forward Sylow calculation to show that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $15$.

**Proof that $A_5$ does not have a subgroup of order $15$**

Prove that a group of order $15$ is cyclic (Sylow's Theorems). Now prove that no permutation on $5$ symbols can have order $15$.

Comment: thanx for the answer, yes I need help proving last part

Comment: @Patience I have left an hint. It must be easy to take it from there. I can however elaborate further but I am sure you can take it yourself.

Comment: @Tojamaru : Another way (if you already know one way) of seeing  $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $15$ is to see that anyy group of order $15$ is cyclic.. this follows similar steps but then it is a little bit generalized case...

Comment: There's a much easier way to see $A_5$ has no subgroup of order 15.  If it had, it would have index 4, and $A_5$ would act transitively on its cosets, providing a non-trivial homomorphism from $A_5$ to $S_4$, contradicting that $A_5$ is simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a computational approach.  In fact, there are $13$ isomorphism classes of groups of order $60$.  These can be accessed by the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) `AllSmallGroups` function.

Here's the input code:

```
for G in AllSmallGroups(60) do
  Conj:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(LatticeSubgroups(G));
  SubgroupSizes:=Set(Conj,C->Size(C[1]));
  Print(StructureDescription(G)," ",IsAbelian(G)," ",SubgroupSizes,"\n");
od;
```

And here is the output:

```
C5 x (C3 : C4) false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C3 x (C5 : C4) false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C15 : C4 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C60 true [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
A5 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 60 ]
C3 x (C5 : C4) false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C15 : C4 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
S3 x D10 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C5 x A4 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 15, 20, 60 ]
C6 x D10 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C10 x S3 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
D60 false [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
C30 x C2 true [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 ]
```

Each row identifies one of the $13$ groups of order $60$, writes whether or not it's abelian, and the list of subgroup sizes of that group.

The notation as to which group is which should be largely self-explanatory, except that ":" represents a [semi-direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

- "$G$ is abelian" is true for $2$ out of $13$ isomorphism classes of groups of order $60$.
- "$G$ has a subgroup of order $30$" is true for $11$ out of $13$.  (The two counter-examples are $A_5$ and $C_5 \times A_4$.)
- "$G$ has a subgroup of order $2$, $3$, and $5$" is true for $13$ out of $13$.
- "$G$ has a subgroup of order $6$, $10$, and $15$" is true for $11$ out of $13$.  (The two counter-examples are $A_5$, which has no subgroup of order $15$, and $C_5 \times A_4$, which has no subgroup of order $6$.)

*Disclaimer*: I don't mean to undermine the importance of understanding the theoretical methods for answering these questions.

Comment: Thank you, @Douglas. Let me add for the reader of this post who will try to use `Subgroups` from the [SONATA package](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sonata.html): as SONATA's manual confirms, `Subgroups` is intended for small examples. Please read [How do I get the subgroups of my group](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) from the GAP F.A.Q. for further hints.

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

As $A_5$ is of order $60$ and a-non abelian group, option A is not true .

Also, $A_5$ is a simple group, so it doesn't have subgroup of order $30$, as a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.  So Option B is also not true.

Now by Cauchy's theorem for finite groups, C must be true.

As we know a group of order $15$ is cyclic, if $A_5$ has a subgroup of order $15$ then that subgroup must be cyclic.  Hence $A_5$ has an element of order $15$, which is a contradiction as $A_5$ doesn't have any elements of order $15$. So in this way option D is also not true.