# Use the Finite Subgroup Test to find all subgroups .

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

a) $$(ℤ_{12} , +_{12} )$$
b) $$((12), ×_{12})$$

I was thinking to use a cayley table to see if that may help, but if someone can provide the proof using the finite subgroup test for these two or help me along the way that would be great!

Comment: a) has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208063/calculation-of-subgroups-of-z-12) I guess.

And b) should be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043723/subgroup-lattice-of-u12) right?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun did you have any suggestions to help on either one?

Answer (score 1):

So the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) states the following:

A nonempty subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if the following properties hold:

- $ \forall a \in H, a^{-1} \in H$
- $a,b \in H \implies ab \in H $

You now could test bruteforce all subsets of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ but that would be a lot to do since there are $\mathcal P(12)$ many subsets.

So lets "guess" the right subsets and then proof with the finite subgroup test if the subset is a subgroup.

Lets use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208063/calculation-of-subgroups-of-z-12) by BobaFret to find the right subsets:

> $\mathbb Z_{12}$ has $\varphi (12)=4$ generators: $1, 5, 7$ and $11$, $Z_{12}=\langle1 \rangle=\langle 5 \rangle=\langle 7 \rangle=\langle 11 \rangle$. Now pick an element of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ that is not a generator, say $2$. Calculate all of the elements in $\langle2 \rangle$.

Following to this we get for example $ H = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ as a subset. Now to proof $H \leq G$ we use the test by writing down all invereses to each element. Note that $e = 0$. Then:
\begin{align*}
2 + 10 \mod 12 = 0 \\
4 + 8 \mod 12 = 0 \\
6 + 6 \mod 12 = 0\\
8 + 4 \mod 12 = 0\\
10 + 2 \mod 12 = 0
\end{align*}
Thats why $H \leq G$ after the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test). To find all subgroups, just test the other subsets like this.