# Let G be a group of order 60.Pick out the true statements:

Tags: group-theory

I came across this problem which says:

Let $G$ be a group of order $60$.Pick out the true statements:

> (a)$\,G$ is abelian,
>
> (b)$\,G$ has a subgroup of order $30,$
>
> (c)$\,G$ has subgroups of order $2,3$ and $5,$
>
> (d)$\,G$ has subgroups of order $6,10$ and $15.$

To tackle the problem,i have used Sylow's first theorem and concluded that G has subgroups of order $2,3$ and $5.$ But i do not know how to determine whether G is abelian or not. Please help.

Comment: I have got it. Since G is an alternating group (A5) and we know that An is abelian iff n<=3, then G can not be abelian. Am i right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group of order $60$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173565/group-of-order-60)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dihedral group $D_{30}$ has order 60. Dihedral groups $D_n$ for $n>2$ are not abelian.

Answer (score 2):

What about $\,A_5\leq S_5\,$...? This must answer (a), (b), and (d) (remember:$\,A_5\,$ is a simple group)

Answer (score 1):

$G$ cannot have a subgroup of order $30$. If so , that should be normal because $[G:H]=2$. But note that there exists a group of order $60$ is simple(eg $A_5$). So option b wrong.

By cauchy's theorem option (c) is true.

Option (d) is not true since $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $15.$

Comment: No, there exists a simple group of order $60$. Not all groups of order $60$ are simple.

Comment: please can you give me a group of order 60 which is not simple.

Comment: All apart from $A_5$ (for example $C_{60}$).

Comment: What is $C_{60}$ is it dihedral group.

Comment: No, the cyclic group (but the dihedral group of order $60$ would of course also be an example).

Comment: ok.i edited. thank you very much